# check if year exists in date variable and format to required format in python?

Tags: python, datetime

I have two types of date variables -

```
d1 = "Mar.30"
d2 = "2-4-2023"
```

how can I format both types of dates into this format- %Y-%b-%d .

IF we don't have year in date variable then we need to append the current year in it.

Expected output-

```
d1 = "2023-03-30"
d2 = "2023-04-02"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The Python `dateutil` module can parse date strings in almost any format.

Comment: Are those supposed to be strings?

Comment: @JohnGordon yes.

Comment: is it always d-m-Y in strings like `2-4-2023`? I think dateuils parser assumes month first by default; but that can be configured.